# PHP can't find database variable

Tags: variables, undefined

I haven't coded in PHP for a while and now I've come back to it, it's updated and I don't really know what I'm doing. I've researched about connecting to a database and doing mysql queries. I've got a connect file and then a separate file for my functions. Then I have an initialize file which requires them both and my initialize file is included in every page.

This is my connect file.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
if($db->connect_errno){
    die('There are connection problems with the server.');
}
```

When I use my database variable in my functions file. I get an error saying that is can't find the variable.

This is the error I get on the webpage:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\functions.php on line 19
```

The connect file is stored in the same 'core' directory.

I hope I've been clear in what the problem is.

Thank you guys for reading and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including connect file into functions.php?

Comment: No, they were both included in the same file. The connect file is first. I've got it working for now by passing in the  $db variable to every function that needs it. It's like the function body can't see the rest of the file

Comment: Glad you solved it. Check if the scope of your $db variable allows it to be visible in functions.php.